# Clustering Points Algorithm

Tags: c++, opencv

I've applied three different methods of getting sets of points as follows. 
Every method produces a vector of Points. Each method is in a different color, red, blue, and green.

[image: Method 1][image: Method 2][image: Method 3]

Here is the combined image, overlaying all 3 of the sets of points

[image]

As you can see in the combined image there are spots in which all three sets "agree" on (i.e are generally in the exact same spot). I would like to find these particular spots and combine them into a single coordinate. I'm not sure where to start with approaching this problem. I've looked into K-means clustering, but to me it seems the problem is that K-means will cluster all the points and take the average with surrounding points, shifting the cluster center from the original position. I could loop through all the points in all the vectors that store the points, but as these images get larger with more points, it becomes very costly and inefficient.

Does anybody have any tips on how to approach this problem? I've been using OpenCV with C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notionally, what you want to do is consider the complete **tripartite graph** on the three sets of points with edges weighted by distance.  Then select edges in order of weight until a **triangle** appears; call those points a corresponding set, choose (say) their centroid to represent them, and **remove** them from the graph.  Stop when the edge length exceeds some **tolerance**.

The **mathematical** justification for this approach is that it is independent of point ordering (except in the unlikely case of problematic ties in distances between points).

The **practical** implementation of this algorithm (for a significant number of points) involves a search data structure that can quickly find **nearby points** (not just the nearest): bins of the threshold size, a quad trie, or a *k*-*d* tree would work.  Probably you would create one for each point set and use the other sets’ points as query points.